# How to check if sample data fit uniform distribution in sql

Tags: sql, math, distribution

I have a x,y data table in SQL database such as

```
12.5,26.3
12.5,26.4
12.6,26.3
12.6,26.4
...
```

How to determine if the dataset is of uniform distribution (or not)

Comment: You should really provide more details if you want to get a meanigful answer. Such as do you have a range for the distribution or should it also be fitted? How many data points you've got? What exactly do you mean by "determine"? Statistical tests can only give you probabilities and there is no certanity with random sources.

Comment: @SergGr Thank you for your reply, the total sample size is over 7,000,000 records and ranged as gps (+90.0000, -90.0000) , (+180.0000,-180.0000), and by my bad english "determine" it means "all the sample data are distributed like...............uniform distribution as if generated by a uniform distribution function"

Comment: In statistics there is no certainty, there is only level of confidence. Even a truly fair coin can come up 100 times heads in a row. It is just very unlikely. Anyway, what have you tried so far? Have you tried some basic things like [Pearson's chi-squared test](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Pearson%27s_chi-squared_test) and [Pearson correlation coefficient](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Pearson_correlation_coefficient)? Where exactly is your problem?

Comment: @SergGr Thank you again for the advice "Pearson's chi-squared test", I have found the solution myself and post a answer below.

Comment: Glad it helped. I'm not sure what your real goal is but depending on it you might need to check for correlation as well. For example, values generated as `latitude = random(-90; 90)`, `longitude = 2 * latitude` hardly can be seen as truly random although independently such `latitude` and `longitude` would pass any randomness test.

Answer (score 0):

Answer my own question:

1. group by lat-lon and create some rectangle on map (precision 0.01 for lat & lon each)

create table tbl_to_check_if_of_uniform_distribution as
SELECT cast(lat*100 as int) as lat100, cast(lon*100 as int) as lon100, count(1) as latlon100cnt from tbl_some_lat_and_lon_as_double group by cast(lat*100 as int), cast(lon*100 as int);

2. check if the rectangle can be described as "uniform distribution" within a bigger rectangle (Pearson's chi-squared test)

I plotted these dots using python and to see if `latlon100cnt` are all the same in a bigger rectangle area, and group by cast(lat*10 as int), cast(lon*10 as int) to see if the variance & max(latlon100cnt)-min(latlon100cnt) sort of thing